# Why isn't the div width/height changing after loading?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to create an online image cropper where the user uploads a photo and it is displayed with a box (frame) that is changeable via buttons.  Crops the photo and sends it back to the user.

I have a basic template of form uploader in php (working). It then displays the image in a `div` with another transparent `div` above it with a border marking the cropping area.

The initial values for the `divs` are set in the css section via php as the page is sent to the user.  I'm trying to adjust the size of the frame `div`, as the width given is the image width +2 px for the frame (same for height) and it should just be the images width (-2 px).

This code should be working, but when the alerts pop up, they show that the frame width/height has not changed the original values, and it appears as though the frame does not change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    width: 500px;
    height: 334px;
    background-color: black;
}

.top {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 334px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    z-index: 999;
}

.bottom {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 334px;
    background-color: green;
//  background-image: url(uploads/1505002267.jpg);
    z-index: 998;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myOnLoad() {
    var w = 500;
    var h = 334;
    var frame = document.getElementsByClassName('top')[0];
    w = w - 2;
    h = h - 2;
    //frame.setAttribute("style", "width: " + w + "px;");
    //frame.setAttribute("style", "height: " + h + "px;");
    frame.style.width = w + "px;";
    frame.style.height = h + "px;";
    alert(frame.offsetWidth);
    alert(frame.offsetHeight);
}
</script>
<title>Test Website</title>
</head>
<body onload="myOnLoad()">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bottom" id="image">
        <div class="top" id="frame">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am aware that I can change the value php gives to the css section, but I'm going to need to change the crop ratio in the next step anyway, so I need this way to work.  Please help, I've been looking at this code for way too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolon in the quotes.

```
frame.style.width = w + "px";
frame.style.height = h + "px";
```

Also, `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` takes border into consideration. Since your border width is 1px, it adds 2px to both height and width of the image canceling out the subtraction with 2.

Read more about offset [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) and [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) on MDN.